# How to securely pass the password in python code while connecting on-premises servers via ec2 instance?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2

I am connecting my on-premise server via SSH (paramiko) from EC2 instance using Python script.While connecting my on-premise I use the credential (hard-coded).

The syntax is :

```
ssh.connect("XX.XXX.XX.XX",XX,"user id","password")
```

I don't want to use the hard-coded password. Could you suggest me to pass the my credentials in a secure way in AWS cloud, Please?

Comment: Sure, use certificates instead. I'm assuming amazon-ec2 supports this without having ever used the library. Of if that's an option, `sys.argv[1]` and pass it as a parameter to your script? or use [getpass.getpass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) and ask for user input?

Comment: @Torxed, The amazon-ec2 instance will be triggered by lambda function based on some batch trigger file. so there wont be any person to give the password.

Comment: That sounds odd. But I'm guessing that's well thought through and there's a reason for doing it that way. Then I definitely think you should be using a certificate.